# Fundamental Representation of $SU(3)$ is a complex representation

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

Let in a $D(R)$ dimensional representation of $SU(N)$ the generators, $T^a$s follow the following commutation rule:
                          $\qquad \qquad \qquad [T^a_R, T^b_R]=if^{abc}T^c_R$.

Now if $-(T^a_R)^* = T^a_R $, the representation $R$ is [real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation). Again if we can find a unitary matrix, $V(\neq I)$ such that

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad  -(T^a_R)^*=V^{-1} T^a_R V  \quad \forall a
$

then the representation $R$ is pseudoreal.

If a representation is neither real nor pseudoreal, the representation $R$ is [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_representation).

**Claim: 
One way to show that a representation is complex is to show that at least one generator matrix $T^a_R$ has eigenvalues that do not come in plus-minus pairs.**

Now let us consider $SU(3)$ group. The generators in the fundamental representation are given by

$T^a =\lambda^a/2; \quad a=1,...8$,
where $\lambda^a$s are the Gell-Mann matrices. We see that $T^8$ has eigenvalues $(1/\sqrt{12}, 1/\sqrt{12}, -1/\sqrt{3} )$.

My doubt is:

**According to the claim, is the fundamental representation of $SU(3)$ a complex representation?**

Comment: An element of the fundamental representation of  $SU(N)$ is a  $n*n$ complex matrix $M$ such that $y^\dagger M^\dagger Mx = y^\dagger x$, for every complex vectors $x, y$.

Comment: This link might be useful: http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/04/complex-real-and-pseudoreal.html

Answer (score 9):

First of all, we are dealing with **unitary** representations, so that the $T^a$s are always **self-adjoint** and the representations have the form
$$U(v) = e^{i \sum_{a=1}^Nv^a T_a}$$
with $v \in \mathbb R^N$. When you say that $U$ is real you just mean that the representation is made of the very **real**, unitary, $n\times n$ matrices $U$. This way, the condition $(T_a)^* = -T_a$ is **equivalent** to the reality (in the proper sense) requirement.

Let us come to your pair of questions.

**(1)**. You are right on your point:

**PROPOSITION**.  *A unitary finite dimensional representation is **complex** (i.e. it is neither real nor pseudoreal) if and only if at least one self-adjoint generator $T_a$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $-\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.*

PROOF

Suppose that $$(T_a)^* = -V T_a V^{-1}\tag{1}$$ for some unitary matrix $V$ and every $a=1,2,3,\ldots, N$. Since we also know that $T_a$ is self-adjoint, there is an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors $u_j^{(a)}\neq 0$, $j=1,\ldots, n$ and the eigenvalues $\lambda_j^{(a)}$ are real. Therefore:
$$T_au_j^{(a)}= \lambda_j^{(a)} u_j^{(a)}\:.$$
Taking the complex conjugation and using (1)
$$VT_aV^{-1}u_j^{(a)*}= -\lambda_j^{(a)} u_j^{(a)*}$$
so that $V^{-1}u_j^{(a)*}\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $T_a$ with eigenvalue $-\lambda_j$. We conclude that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $-\lambda$ is (consequently, if the dimension of the space is odd, $0$ must necessarily be an eigenvalue as well).

Soppose,*vice versa*, that for the self-adjoint matrix $T^a$ its (real) eigenvalues satisfy the constraint that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $-\lambda$ is. As $T^a$ is self adjoint, there is a unitary matrix such that:
$$T_a  = U diag(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \lambda_2, -\lambda_2,..., \lambda_{n/2},-\lambda_{n/2}) U^{-1}$$
when $n$ is even, otherwise there is a further vanishing last element on the diagonal.
Thus
$$T^*_a  = U^* diag(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \lambda_2, -\lambda_2,..., \lambda_{n/2},-\lambda_{n/2}) U^{-1*}$$
Notice that $U^*$ is unitary if $U$ is such.
Let us indicate by $e_1,e_2, \ldots, e_n$ the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $T^a$ where the matrix takes the above diagonal form.
If $W$ is the (real) unitary matrix which swaps $e_1$ with $e_2$, $e_3$ with $e_4$ and so on (leaving $e_n$ fixed if $n$ is odd), we have that 
$$W diag(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \lambda_2, -\lambda_2,..., \lambda_{n/2},-\lambda_{n/2}) W^{-1} = - diag(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \lambda_2, -\lambda_2,..., \lambda_{n/2},-\lambda_{n/2})$$ and thus
$$T^*_a = U^*W^{-1}(- UT_aU^{-1})  WU^{-1*} = -S T_a S^{-1}$$
with $S= U^*W^{-1}U$, which is unitary because composition of unitary matrices.

We can conclude that, as you claim, a way to show that a representation is complex (i.e. it is not real) is to show that at least one generator matrix $T_a$ has (non-vanishing) eigenvalues that do not come in plus-minus pairs.

QED

**(2)**. In view of **(1)**, if the list of eigenvalues you presented is correct, the considered representation is obviously complex.

Answer (score 0):

The N-dimensional fundamental representation of SU(N) for N greater than two is a complex representation whose complex conjugate is often called the antifundamental representation.

Thus SU(3) fundamental representation is a complex representation.

(see for example: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_representation))

Comment: see also [this post: complex-representation-of-a-gauge-group-and-a-chiral-gauge-theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96520/)