# Real representation is physically real?

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

In Peskin & Schroder, [Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/qftbook.html)  equation (15.82) states that

$$ t^a_{\bar{r}} = -(t^a_{r})^* = (t^a_{r})^T $$

Why is the representation which satisfies

$$ t_{\overline{r}}^{a}=Ut_{r}^{a}U^{\dagger} $$

called [real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation)?

Does this real means something physically real?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69443/2451

Comment: @user49115 : In particular, there is a wikipedia link in the question which Qmachanic mentions on [Real Representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation). You see the statement in the first sentence of the third paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

This means mathematically real, that is, a [real-valued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-valued_function) representation.

Have you studied the [Representation Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) of (Lie) Groups and of [Lie Algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation)?

A representation may be real, in which the matrices that represent the linear action of the group element are matrices with real-valued elements. We than say that the matrices are in some subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Converserly, a representation may be [Complex-Valued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex-valued_function), and have matrices which are in some subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

In fact, if you had looked at equation (15.82) in Peskin & Schroeder, which is defining the [Conjugate Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_representation) $\bar{r}$ or some representation $r$

$$ t^a_{\bar{r}} = - (t^a_{r})^* = - (t^a_{r})T $$

you would see in the following paragraph he explains his definition of a **real** representation $r$ to be one for which

$$ r \equiv \bar{r} $$

That is, for $r$ to be real, there must be a unitary transformation

$$ t^a_{\bar{r}} = U t^a_r U^{\dagger}  $$

as you say, and the complex-conjugate operation above is trivial. Equivalently, $r$ must be real-valued.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to also ask the related question about sentence of the below (19.129) at p.678 (Peskin). He explains a gauge-invariant mass term by using the fact of real representation. Do you know how does this related to it?

Comment: @user49115 : If it is a new question then please post it as such, and I'll take a look if I can.
Also, if this answered your first question, don't be afraid to accept it! Although in general it is advised to wait a day or two in case anyone else comes along with something better!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I use another post for the related question.

Comment: @user49115 : Not at all, I'm happy to help!

Comment: If the representation r is real, how can we see the invariance of $G_{ab}\eta_{a}\xi_{b}$?